# mime type torrent codeigniter to upload file

Tags: php, codeigniter, mime-types

I'm trying to upload "torrent" files to server but I get an error "The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed."
i edited the file mime.php:

```
'btt'   =>  'application/x-bittorrent',
```

who can help me?

Comment: Do a `print_r($this->upload->data());` and see what the mime type on the file is.

Comment: Hi dan,
Thanks for answering. the "array" shows me this:
[file_name] => torrent.torrent
[file_type] => application/force-download]

then i added this to the mime.php file:
'btt' => array('application/x-bittorrent', 'application/force-download', 'application/torrent', 'torrent'),

but It does not work :/

Comment: Do you have that listed in your `application/config/mimes.php` file?

Comment: yes, I added this:

btt' => array('application/x-bittorrent', 'application/force-download', 'application/torrent', 'torrent'),

in my mimes.php

Comment: Is there a `mime_type` listed in the print out of the data? In addition to the `file_type`?

Answer (score 0):

my solution was:

```
if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'application/x-bittorrent'){
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
}
```